# Copy file from Azure File Storage to Blob

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azure-file-copy

I'm using copy data that copies a file from File Share to Blob. I always get this error:

'''
ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToCreateAzureBlobContainer,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Unable to create Azure Blob container. Endpoint: https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/, Container Name: temp-archive.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=Unable to connect to the remote server,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=Unable to connect to the remote server,Source=System,''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx,Source=System,'
'''

Both blob and file share storage are correctly setup as I used them in my pipeline. only when I'm copying from file share to blob that this happens. Is it a limitation?

Comment: Could you `Test connection` again in your azure blob and file storage connection to make sure the connections are valid?

Comment: yes they are successfully connecting...

Comment: I test it on my side, it works fine, there may be some other settings in your ADF that affect it,  could you create a new ADF to have a try?

Comment: were you able to copy it from a File Storage (Storage Account A) to Blob (Storage Account B)? Or you used the same storage account? I'm transferring to a different storage account. I wonder if that's a limitation?

Comment: Yes, I was able to copy it between different storage account, could you create a new ADF to have a try?

Answer (score 1):

Please do these steps to identify the error:

1. Tested the connection of the linked services of file Storage and Blob Storage.
   [image]
2. Preview the source data to test if the connection works well. If so, then the error is caused by sink side.
3. Delete and recreate the linked service of sink dataset.
4. Check the Blob Storage firewall if Data Factory can access it.

Comment: So now, it's connecting successfully (intermittently), after I turned on in Copy Data > Settings > Enable staging. Could there be an issue if the File Storage (source) is using private runtime  while the destination blob is using public runtime? I could see now that it's connecting successfully... but intermittent.

Comment: @kayeesp no very sure, the staging is no checked by default. Please unchecked it and test for some times.

Comment: Hi @kayeesp, hope you're doing well. do you get any progresses?

Comment: The root cause is when we're copying from a private integration runtime to public integration runtime... Microsoft limitation.